# what is the code for table rates shipping method & cash on delivery" payment method

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, payment-methods, table-rates, cash-on-delivery

I am using this shipping "Table rates" and "webshopapp matrix rates" shipping methods.

what i need is that , if  we use table rates shipping method, i want to hide "cash on delivery" payment method.

i am following this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604267/magento-onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method

please help me to find what is the code for

1)table rates shipping method

2)cash on delivery" payment method....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS i have seen in your reference link you can also see

code for

1) table rates shipping method  == `flatrate_flatrate`

2) cash on delivery" payment method. == `cashondelivery`

**EDIT**

```
class Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    /**
     * code name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'tablerate';
}
```

Simple Magento shipping method code

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => flatrate_flatrate
                            [label] => Fixed
                        )

                )

            [label] => Flat Rate
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => freeshipping_freeshipping
                            [label] => Free
                        )

                )

            [label] => Free Shipping
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => tablerate_bestway
                            [label] => Table Rate
                        )

                )

            [label] => Best Way
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => Array
                (
                )

            [label] => Best Way
        )

)
```

i am sure it will help you.

Comment: i will check and tell you soon....

Comment: cod is worked fine..... but flatrate_flatrate code is "Flat rate", I want code for "Table rates"

Comment: @BabyinMagento2, you can see class for tablerate in my edited answer

Comment: i used "tablerate" as table rate shipping method code, but it did't worked for me....

can you please tell me the "table rate code".

or

please tell me in which file i have to place the above code....

Comment: try tablerate_tablerate may be work as per other  class of shipment.

Comment: tried that too, but did't worked......

Comment: in that post, he told from this : "echo $_code = $_method->getCode();" we can find shipping method code.

i dont know how? can you give me some idea....

Comment: See my updated answer, as i have enable 3 method from default magento source

Comment: thanks a lot ....   "tablerate_bestway" code did the magic.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento2,i am glad. i could help you. ;)

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?

Comment: Throught the (M2) rest API I found this also is correct: "shipping_method_code": "bestway", "shipping_carrier_code": "tablerate". For anyone who uses it.